# Create custom List LINQ Expression

Tags: custom-list, csom, sharepoint-fields

I have a list on SharePoint, where I am trying to load fields for this list like following:

```
        var lists = context.Web.Lists;
        context.Load(lists, n => n.Include(x => x.Title,
                                           x => x.Fields.Include(
                                               z => z.Title, 
                                               z => z.InternalName, 
                                               z => z.TypeDisplayName)));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The following part of the code I use quite often in my code, while working with other lists:

```
                          x => x.Fields.Include(
                                               z => z.Title, 
                                               z => z.InternalName, 
                                               z => z.TypeDisplayName)
```

I would like to know if there is a way how to simplify inserting this `.Include` statement in my code (so that in case I will have to add more properties in the future, I dont have to rewrite all my code everywhere but only in one place).

I have tried to create custom LINQ Extension, but it failed as it is probably expecting sort of a `Expression<Func<T,Y>>` (I guess).

Any help regarding this matter would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result I was looking for:

```
 private static readonly Expression<Func<Field, Object>>[] LoadFieldProperties = { term => term.InternalName,
                                                                                   term => term.Title,
                                                                                   term => term.TypeDisplayName};
```

and then call it like following:

```
var lists = context.Web.Lists;
context.Load(lists, n => n.Include(x => x.Title,
                                        x => x.Fields.Include(LoadFieldProperties)));
```